# write file in network shared folder with UnauthorizedAccessException?

Tags: file, windows-mobile, networking, windows-ce

hi the win mobile 6 code tries to write files on network shared folder, but always gets UnauthorizedAccessException. I have checked permission and security setting on the folder and the code can read the file but just cant write to it. The code runs under administrator account which has full control over the folder and files. It is in vs 2008 professional with device emulator.Any help please? thanks very much.

Comment: i marked the answer when it helps anyhow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've verified that you can write the file outside of your program, correct? i.e. logged into a machine account and tried placing that specific file there.

Do you have access to the system that hosts the file?  If so, you can check it's access logs to verify which account your app is using.

My guess would be that either your app isn't using the account you think it is, or that the admin account may doesn't actually have write access to that folder or file.

Comment: there is a shared permission i didnt check,oops